# Incremental Append and incremental insert

Tags: pyspark, append, azure-data-factory

I would like to understand how to perform incremental Append using pyspark in databricks and write data into delta table..also
1)what is difference between incremental Append and incremental upsert ??

Answer (score 0):

- Append feature allows to add partitions to an existing Parquet file without having to rewrite existing partitions. That is, every day, we will append partitions to the existing Parquet file. With Spark, this is done by using .mode("append") when writing the DataFrame.

https://joydipnath.medium.com/incremental-data-loading-with-apache-spark-concept-with-special-parquet-file-feature-of-increment-ebaa89897cff

- Incremental Upsert allows to update existing records and insert new records based on identified keys from an incremental/delta feed.To implement the same in PySpark on a partitioned dataset, we would take help of Dynamic Partition Overwrite.

https://subhamkharwal.medium.com/pyspark-upsert-or-scd1-with-dynamic-overwrite-1f55103e22a0